# How to check if a host is unreachable?

Tags: java, networking, ping, icmp

I am trying to get the unreachable condition of the ping host as I am getting just (0,1) value for up and down respectively, how would I get any condition "2" at which it tell me unreachable ping host?

My code,

```
import java.net.InetAddress;

public class PingExample 
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
try
{
InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName("172.16.2.0");
// Try to reach the specified address within the timeout
// periode. If during this periode the address cannot be
// reach then the method returns false.
boolean reachable = address.isReachable(10000);
System.out.println("Is host reachable? " + reachable);
} catch (Exception e)
{
e.printStackTrace();
}
}
}
```

What is active and passive state? How can I check it?

---

**Edit:** see at this link page 26
http://nagios.sourceforge.net/docs/ndoutils/NDOUtils_DB_Model.pdf

stat column description. I want to get this result as I had posted my code, so how would I get that column "state"? Remember I am using loop for "n" hosts.

Comment: I cannot understand your question.

Comment: You might like to go through 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/195070/what-is-the-quickest-way-to-detect-an-unreachable-host-in-java

Comment: @STephen i can get either up or down through my this code how would i know that host is unreachacble ??

Comment: You are still not making sense to me.  The code in your question tests to see if the host is reachable or not.  Please read the javadoc for the `InetAddress.isReachable()` method ... carefully.

Comment: @Stephen yup i am doing as you told above but the main thing is that either host would be reachable or not so i can use these two conditions to show that either host would be up or down what about host not reachable how would i show that host is not reachable ??

Comment: I tried to edit your question, but still i dont think people here can understand, please modify your question.

Comment: Please **explain** what you mean by "up" / "down" / "reachable" / "unreachable".  What is the **technical** difference between (for instance) "down" and "unreachable"? What mechanism do you propose that would reliably distinguish these two states?  (Personally, I think you are just using the words without having a clear understanding of what they mean.)

Comment: @Stephen "Up" means host pinged "down" means tried to ping but fail because sys is off and "unreachable" means that it tried to ping but connection did not completed so that it would tell either the pinged host is "up" or "down"!

Comment: First see http://www.0x13.de/index.php/code-snippets/74-icmp-ping-in-java.html

"unreachable" could mean that no routing can be determined ("route print"). "down" could mean a "connection refused" ICMP reply or a timeout?

Comment: @Stephen and Mgaert i did not intend to waist your time mates i am going to try to make my question more simpler.. . my concept cleared by your view i edited my post so please Check It !

Comment: To Start, Do Not Write Titles Like This, It Makes Them Very Hard To Read. I Have Edited It. As Far As I See, This Is Not The First Time. Please Pay Attention To Edits By Others On Your Questions So That You Can Possibly Learn From It.

Comment: @Balus Thanks for paying my attention towards my lacking and do you have any suggestions for the edit question ?

Comment: `InetAddress.getByName()` only does a DSN lookup, and since successful lookups are cached, it will continue returning `true` for a while until the cache is invalidated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "Up" means host pinged "down" means tried to ping but fail because sys is off and "unreachable" means that it tried to ping but connection did not completed so that it would tell either the pinged host is "up" or "down"!

This does not make sense from a technical perspective, and I suspect that means that what you are trying to do doesn't make any sense either.

For the record:

- Ping doesn't involve making connections.  It it is a simple request and response.  What happens is that an ICMP Echo Request packet is sent, and you wait for a few seconds to see if you get an ICMP Echo Reply packet.
- You might also get an ICMP Network Unreachable or an ICMP Host Unreachable ... if the packet cannot be routed.
- You might also get ... nothing.  You can't reliably distinguish between "system is broken / off", "packets are getting lost by the network", "packets are being filtered out" and "system doesn't exist".  These all give you ... no reply, in some cases.
- These days, responses (or non-responses) to pings are often due to firewalls blocking unwanted traffic and the like.

So what this all means that it is not possible to reliably distinguish between "down" and "unreachable" ... even if you could provide an explanation for a distinction that made technical sense.

And we haven't talked about how much of this information makes it back to a Java application.